# How to use the multithreading concepts and deadlock concept in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I will connect with one database from several machines. In all machines they need to insert the data in single table. In that time: how to use multithreading and deadlock concepts? Using the MySQL database and also MS Access.

Comment: The question is vague. if your .NET application is using SQLs, the database transaction will handle the concurrency issues.  Since you are doing INSERT, you may lock the table, but this is highly not recommended.  From the client 's perspective, there is no need to handle m-threading and deadlocks.

Comment: You don't use deadlock concepts, you try to avoid them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about an SQL server (MySQL) then the thread safty is not your problem. It's hard to tell what you are talking about. A bit more information would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to avoid these issues is to use proper locking/coding techniques:

eg:

updating a value in a field use:

```
UPDATE table SET data=data+23 WHERE id=7
```

and not

```
@data = SELECT data FROM table WHERE id=7
@data = @data + 23
UPDATE table SET data=@data WHERE id=7
```

or use transactions, it really depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to exand your question a little, I can try to give you more examples.